# GridView hyperLink field to redirect to another web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've binded URLs of websites to a hyper Link filed in a grid view. So now how can navigate to the actual website? Something like "www.google.com"???

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("WebPageName") %>'
```

and it has to be opened in another separate tab not in the same page. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Thanks for Praveen, Sebastian Siek and Adrian Iftode. You guys gave some good ideas that helped me to solve my problem:

This is the solution I found:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Target="HyperLink"
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("http://{0}", Eval("WebPage").ToString()) %>' 
Text='<%# Bind("WebPage") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use Target="_parent" for the HyperLinkField which will open the site in the same page.

Comment: Yea ur "Target" is the solution to open url in another tab. Thanx alot

Answer (score 1):

If this is only a link, I would suggest using native html element - a (one server side control less on the page).

```
<a href="<%# Eval("WebPageName") %>" target="" title="">MyLink</a>
```

hope it helps.

Comment: sure, have a look at this link - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs

Comment: also make sure the url contains the http part also

Comment: But the filed text also has to change dynamically. Is it possible it HTML Tag? the reason for asking is HTML "a" Tag doesn't have Text property.

Comment: @AdrianIftode Yea that "http" part helped. Thanx for ur help

Comment: If you can bind Text property in the same way as the href, then you will be fine. If there's any "fancy" stuff that needs to be done behind the scene to generate Text, then you need you use server side HyperLink (or create method generate text).